# How to get MailChimp or Mandrill Unsubscribe URL dynamically with HTML?

Tags: php, mailchimp, mandrill

From MailChimp We have

```
*|UNSUB|*
```

When I checked the link it seems to be User Id & List Id is there.

Mailchimp HTML Looks like

```
<a href="https://abc.us18.list-manage.com/unsubscribe?u=9af1bf4f22cb38f0674435c0d&amp;id=a23353ca69&amp;e=e1d7cd9010&amp;c=4151ad6cc6" style="text-decoration:none;color:#656565;font-weight:normal" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://abc.us18.list-manage.com/unsubscribe?u%3D9af1bf4f22cb38f0674435c0d%26id%3Da23353ca69%26e%3De1d7cd9010%26c%3D4151ad6cc6&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1613552479269000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFDQ849QRIjTXOr07M_cDilrkjaSw"><span style="color:#f2776e">unsubscribe</span></a>
```

Once I send this email template to Mandrill. It's not showing Unsubscribe URL.

Then I go to Settings -> Sending Defaults -> Checked 'Add Unsubscribe Footer'.

Then it's ending end of the page.

It's HTML looks like

```
https://mandrillapp.com/track/click/31061111/mandrillapp.com?p=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
```

Once clicked here, you are directly "Unsubscribe". It's not asking like MailChimp reason to Unsubscribe then Submit.

What I am looking for

1. How we can create dynamic Unsubcribe URL in MailChimp via Code.
2. Mandrill 'Unsubcribe' link is at the bottom of the page, how to get that HTML, so I can place it any where in the email.